# I want to deploy ASP.Net Mvc application inside virtual directory of existing angular6 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, iis-7.5

I have an existing Angular website in that I want to deploy ASP.NET MVC application inside the virtual directory. the problem is when I try to route to ASP.NET MVC application inside a virtual directory it shows "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." error on IIS.

I tried adding a new url rewrite rule in web.config of an angular application as given in

https://www.stefanoscerra.it/iis-rewrite-rules-configuration-angular-web-config/

but it tries to find the angular route and if not match any angular route it redirects to the angular default route

Answer (score 0):

In I was having same scenario like this I solved by adding rewrite rule URL rewrite configuration in web.config .You will need to add rewrite rule like below.

```
<rule name="mvcinsideangularrule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="mvcvirtualdir/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://yourdomain.com/mvcvirtualdir/{R:1}/{R:2}/{R:3}"/>
</rule>
```

It will work in your scenario.

[image: your rewrite configuration in IIS will look like..]